# Android studio does not see virtualization enabled in my pc?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio, and it's working well, on the mobile device, but when I used it with emulator, I noticed a problem.
Look at the picture, although I activated the option to Visualization enabled.

[image]

Comment: Or this? https://www.thecodecity.com/2017/01/intel-haxm-is-required-to-run-this-avd.html

Answer (score 0):

You Have to enable virtualization in BIOS

Comment: Yes i have enable it